# embedded ApacheDS in my application, it fails on service.startup() -> DefaultSchemaService.getSchemaManager() returns null

Tags: java, ldap, apacheds

I'm trying to run an embedded ApacheDS in my application. After reading: [Running Apache DS embedded in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560230/running-apache-ds-embedded-in-my-application)
and http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/1.5/41-embedding-apacheds-into-an-application.html

Using the last stable version 1.5.7,
this simple example fails when executing "service.startup();"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.directory.server.core.schema.DefaultSchemaService.initialize(DefaultSchemaService.java:380)
    at org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService.initialize(DefaultDirectoryService.java:1425)
    at org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService.startup(DefaultDirectoryService.java:907)
    at Test3.runServer(Test3.java:41)
    at Test3.main(Test3.java:24)
```

that is, DefaultSchemaService.getSchemaManager() returns null.

source code:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

import org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService;
import org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.Partition;
import org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.impl.btree.jdbm.JdbmPartition;
import org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapServer;
import org.apache.directory.server.protocol.shared.transport.TcpTransport;
import org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.entry.ServerEntry;
import org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.name.DN;


public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        runServer();
        testClient();
    }

    static void runServer() throws Exception {
        DefaultDirectoryService service = new DefaultDirectoryService();
        service.getChangeLog().setEnabled(false);

        Partition partition = new JdbmPartition();
        partition.setId("apache");
        partition.setSuffix("dc=apache,dc=org");
        service.addPartition(partition);

        LdapServer ldapService = new LdapServer();
        ldapService.setTransports(new TcpTransport(1400));
        ldapService.setDirectoryService(service);

        service.startup();

        // Inject the apache root entry if it does not already exist
        try {
            service.getAdminSession().lookup(partition.getSuffixDn());
        } catch (Exception lnnfe) {
            DN dnApache = new DN("dc=Apache,dc=Org");
            ServerEntry entryApache = service.newEntry(dnApache);
            entryApache.add("objectClass", "top", "domain", "extensibleObject");
            entryApache.add("dc", "Apache");
            service.getAdminSession().add(entryApache);
        }

        DN dnApache = new DN("dc=Apache,dc=Org");
        ServerEntry entryApache = service.newEntry(dnApache);
        entryApache.add("objectClass", "top", "domain", "extensibleObject");
        entryApache.add("dc", "Apache");
        service.getAdminSession().add(entryApache);

        ldapService.start();
    }


    static void testClient() throws NamingException {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        p.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:1400/");
        p.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=admin,ou=system");
        p.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
        p.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

        DirContext rootCtx = new InitialDirContext(p);
        DirContext ctx = (DirContext) rootCtx.lookup("dc=apache,dc=org");
        SearchControls sc = new SearchControls();
        sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchResults = ctx.search("", "(objectclass=*)", sc);

        while (searchResults.hasMoreElements()) {
            SearchResult searchResult = searchResults.next();
            Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
            System.out.println("searchResult.attributes: " + attributes) ;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that ApacheDS versions 1.5.x are not backward compatible.

In ApacheDS 1.5.4 the call "service.startup();" works ok (but it fails somewhere else).

Any idea how to make this example work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this version of ApacheDS needs to explicitely define the working directory:

```
service.setWorkingDirectory(new File("data"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently face the similar problem, and after long googling, finally find something useful

Example for Embedded Apache Directory using 1.5.7

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/documentation/samples/trunk/embedded-sample/src/main/java/org/apache/directory/seserver/EmbeddedADSVer157.java

and also have a look the pom.xml

Pom.xml Example for Embedded Apache Directory using 1.5.7

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/documentation/samples/trunk/embedded-sample/pom.xml

Hope is help!

Comment: Please write some summary from the link, so that your answer will still be useful even if your link dead.

Comment: Thanks goFirendiAsgard