# Embedded/memory LDAP server solution

Tags: memory, ldap

I have a java web application.I want to create an embedded LDAP server, when web application run, I will insert some record to LDAP, and there is another web application will access this LDAP to get information. is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good embeddable Java LDAP server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337756/what-is-a-good-embeddable-java-ldap-server)

Comment: That's correct. but none of them got my answer

Answer (score 4):

Yes. [OpenDS](http://www.opends.org/) can be embedded. If you don't need a full-fledged directory server, for example for testing, the UnboundID [LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) provides an in-memory LDAP server. [See this article](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/ldap-in-memory-directory-server-using-unboundid-ldap-sdk/) for more information and an example.

Comment: Although OpenDS can be embedded, but seems it store data in file system. I have try UnboundID, it's a solution, but it's designed for testing, is it powerful enough to be in product environment?

Comment: No. It is not designed for a production environment.